# I'm repeatedly setting the same variables. How to reuse code block to make this DRY?

Tags: templating, variable, dry

I have a very complex layout which is requiring me to have quite a few {% for %} loops on the page and in each loop I need to set a bunch of variables. In order to make my template more DRY I was hoping I could save that block of code where I set the variables as a partial so I could simply include that partial in each loop rather than writing out each variable that needs to be set every time.

But that doesn't work. Variables in the parent templates are available to imported partials, but variables in partials aren't available to the rest of the parent.

**What other templating options does Craft/Twig supply that would allow me to make this DRY?**

Example of the variables I'm repeatedly setting on multiple loops in the page:

```
{% if article.newsHero | length %}
  {% set photo = article.newsHero.first().url('w600') %}
  {% set w = article.newsHero.first().width() %}
  {% set h = article.newsHero.first().height() %}
{% endif %}
{% set cat = article.newsCategory.first().title %}
{% set summary = article.newsArticle.type('text').first().text|hacksaw(words='35', append='...') %}
{% set count = loop.index %}
```